# Batch file doesn't work properly, can't find my mistake

Tags: batch-file

I just wanted to write a little script in a batch file for learning some programming. But it doesn't matter what I type in for a Input, all I get it the `Invalid Option` output... I searched for the mistake for so long now and didn't find anything... Hope somebody can help me, Thanks in advance!

```
@ECHO OFF
::This script will check if there are any available updates for software via Winget and will let you update all
ECHO Searching for updates...
ECHO =======================================================================
winget upgrade
ECHO =======================================================================
:ask
set INPUT = 
SET /p INPUT = Do you want to update all[Y/N]? %=%
IF /i "%INPUT%" == "Y" GOTO yes
IF /i "%INPUT%" == "N" GOTO no
ECHO Invalid Option
GOTO ask
:yes
ECHO Udating all available packages...
winget upgrade --all
GOTO end
:no
GOTO end
:end
cmd /k
```

Comment: The `=` operator is the command token that seperates variable name and value. whitespace is included in variable names and as well as values- therefor you never define `Input`, you define `input ` with trailing space. For single character input, it is far simpler and safer to use the `Choice` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ***SET /p INPUT=Do you want to update all[Y/N]? %=%***

No space before and after =

Comment: You should remove the useless `%=%` suffix as it serves no purpose…